# Pasting column data to a specific location in a series of sheets in Excel via Macro

Tags: vba, excel

Hi I have an issue to solve. Appreciate if someone can help me on the following.

In `Master Sheet` I've got something similar

```
Item        Price 1   Price 2    Price 3
Apple        12         25          30
Orange       20         12          13
Berry         5          6           3
```

And then on the same excel doc I have say Sheet1, Sheet2 and Sheet3. I need to run a macro so that once it has run 3 sheets will look like below. And when Its copied in to a sheet the location (cell) should be a pre determined one. Can some one throw me a clue?

**Sheet1:**

```
Apple
12
25
30
```

**Sheet2:**

```
Orange
20
12
13
```

**Sheet3:**

```
Berry
5
6
3
```

**Edit:** This edit is in connection with the answer made by **Alex P**

```
 Item        Price 1   Price 2    Price 3
Apple        12                     30
Orange       20         12          13
Berry         5          6           3
```

Here under **Apple** there is no price for **Price 2**. So how do I reflect that in sheet 1 as follows when it is printed? In other words if there is a blank on the sequence, when data is copied to the chosen sheet, the blank cell should be ignored so the data is in a sequence without an empty cell in between.

```
           **Apple**
Price 1       12
Price 3       30
```

Instead of having;

```
           **Apple**
Price 1       12
Price 2     (Blank cell)
Price 3       30
```

Also I would like to have Price1,2,3... printed alongside the numbers as shown above.

**EDIT 2**

The solution by Alex works if the table is located as follows;
[image]

Could you please tell me how do I change the code `Set items = Range("A2:A" & Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row)` to get the same results if I change the table location to following. I've been trying hard to crack this but couldn't get through. I tried changing it to `Set items = Range("C8:C" & Range("C7").End(xlDown).Row)` but no good on the result when printed

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested this and it worked for me.

You'll need to perhaps change the range references to suit your needs.

```
Sub SplitTableData()
    Dim items As Range, item As Range, sht As Long

    Set items = Range("A2:A" & Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row)
    sht = 1

    For Each item In items

        With Worksheets("Sheet" & sht)
            .Range("A1") = item
            .Range("A2") = item.Offset(0, 1)
            .Range("A3") = item.Offset(0, 2)
            .Range("A4") = item.Offset(0, 3)
        End With

        sht = sht + 1
    Next item
End Sub
```

**EDIT**: *updated code based on amended request*

```
Sub SplitTableData()
    Dim items As Range, item As Range, sht As Long, col As Long, rw As Long

    Set items = Range("A2:A" & Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row)
    sht = 1
    rw = 2

    For Each item In items

        With Worksheets("Sheet" & sht)
            .Range("B1") = item

                For col = 2 To 4
                    If item.Offset(0, col - 1) <> vbNullString Then
                        .Range("A" & rw) = Cells(1, col)
                        .Range("B" & rw) = item.Offset(0, col - 1)
                        rw = rw + 1
                    End If
                Next col

        End With

        sht = sht + 1
        rw = 2
    Next item
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for the response. Can you help me understand 'Set items = Range("A2:A" & Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row)'? I don't get the rationale of A2:A then another range A1. Thanks :)

Comment: It basically gets the last row in the data table. If your data table is always a fixed length (e.g. "A1:A10") then you can hard code the range. The way i did it works for any length of table i.e. it's more generic

Comment: Thank you. And @Alex P can I also ask two more questions with regard to this? Really appreciate you help. I have edited my question above and great if you can have a look and suggest a workaround. Should that be a different question, pls do advise. Thanks again.

Comment: hi can I ask for one last help to close this? :) I've an EDIT 2 in the question and hope you don't mind helping me.

Comment: That ought to work? Have you tried hard coding the range i.e. `Range("C8:C10")`?

Comment: Alex P Yes, but I don't get the Price 1, Price 2 etc; The column that suppose to have that always stays blank!

Comment: Try changing `col 2 to 4` to `col 4 to 6`. I think that is the issue.